# Xamarin Forms Android keyboard decimal separator

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I use this code to convert value:

```
v = double.Parse(entry1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

in iOS it's all right - I entering 3,2 and it convert it to 3.2

But in Android, I can't enter a dot between numbers - only comma
But when I enter 3,2 it converts it to 32!  Device language - Russian.
Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
V = double.parse(entry1.Text.Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Please do not forget to mark your answer, it will help others who have simialr issue.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that, you have set your view property like as below:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

convert **android:inputType="number"** to **android:inputType="numberDecimal"**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

---

**Edited :** 
Or you could try removing comma from the value.

```
try { 
    doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.')); 
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
    //Error 
}
```

Comment: I use Xamarin Forms, not Android Studio

Comment: Usually I don't work on Xamarin , but For your statement **But in Android, I can't enter a dot between numbers**, Like when we face issue, it means some property prevents keyboard to input dots, means possible that it should setted as **number** only but for accept dots it should set as **numberDecimal**. Might be possible this.

Comment: When Device Language is English, Its all right < but when Russian it causes an issue\

Comment: Okay then you should try some patch like this -> `try {
            doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.'));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Error
        }`

Comment: No, it doesn't helps

Comment: @BogdanReznikov Great, you found your solution, you should mark this as correct, so that other can find this and get easily rid of this kind of issue.